# BBcode on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, formatting

Can somebody please explain how to post CODE in here?

I followed this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1189729 but it doesn't work for me. I copy and paste a code from Terminal and paste it here in [code]test[/code] but it doesn't work don't know I used this [code][/code] in different forums it worked.

Comment: Read this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1006656

Comment: [code]it doesn't work either I even copied example from this link and paste it in here[/code]
[code]
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    alert("Hello world!");
//-->
</script>
[/code]

Comment: That link won't help you **here** on **Ask Ubuntu** but in **Ubuntu forums**. If you want help with formating in Ask Ubuntu check the link in Oli's answer.

Comment: ok I will check it.

Comment: @Mateo Don't encourage the use of HTML *please* >.<

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few answers, you can take your pick from:

- We aren't Ubuntu Forums, we're Ask Ubuntu.
- The software the drives the two websites is different.
- We don't use BBCode, we use [Markdown (see this link for formatting guides, including code)](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

**tldr** For blocks of code, prepend the line with four spaces, for shorter blocks, wrap in `` (backticks).

Comment: ok I got it now

Comment: Or select the whole block and do ctrl-k!